# Should we always return some value from recursion?

Tags: recursion

I am writing the function where I am using recursive call. In it, I am updating the values in static variable, instead of returning the value. I have provided the condition to end the recursion call. The function works well without returning the value.

I want to understand that is it compulsory to have a statement in recursive function which returns some value?

Comment: if it works then it works

Comment: If by static variable you mean a variable that is only accessible in the scope of your function, then how does the calling code get hold of the result? Or is the recursive function just used for side effects? Posting the actual code might help to clarify.

Comment: @uselpa, i'm sure (by the fact that it is working for him) that he means static like those class variables you define as static in java/c++.

as for the original question: No, not really.
Some view it as a cleaner way of coding but it is not compulsory (as sg.cc said, if it works then it works)

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. @uselpa, I am declaring class level static variable.